# Flexbox not responding when used in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I have three columns of text that I want positioned next to each other in a row. I used flex box to do this but when I shrink the browser to a certain point they just disappear instead of shrinking? I tried setting them to flex-shrink: 1; but it wasn't working either. Im fairly new to this so any help would be appreciated.

```css
.carousel-item { 
  min-height: 450px;
  width: 100%; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
}
 

.carousel-container{
  position: relative;  
  background: url("../img/keyindoorbanner2.jpg") center center no-repeat scroll;
  width: 100%;  
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  text-align: center; 
}

.flex-container{
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-around; 
  align-items: center;
  height: 350px;


}

.flex-container div { 
  flex: 0 1 200px;  
  font-size: 18px;
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="carousel-container">
   <h5 class="reviews-title">TITLE</h5>
   <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
     </ol>
     <div class="carousel-item active" id="firstslide">
     <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
     <div class="flex-container">
     <div class="reviews-text1">"text"
       <p class="reviews-buyername1">-Name</p></div>
     <div class="reviews-text2">"text"
       <p class="reviews-buyername2">-Name</p></div>
     <div class="reviews-text3">"text"
       <p class="reviews-buyername3">-Name</p></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
     <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
     <div class="flex-container">
     <div class="reviews-text1"> "text"
      <p class="reviews-buyername1">-Name</p></div>
     <div class="reviews-text2">"text"
      <p class="reviews-buyername2">-Name</p></div>
     <div class="reviews-text3">"text"
       <p class="reviews-buyername3">-Name</p></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
     <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
     <div class="flex-container">
     <div class="reviews-text1">"text"
      <p class="reviews-buyername1">-Name</p></div>
     <div class="reviews-text2">"text"
      <p class="reviews-buyername2">-Name</p></div>
     <div class="reviews-text3">"text"
      <p class="reviews-buyername3">-Name</p></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
       <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
       </a>
       <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: At what point do things disappear? I'm not seeing anything disappear as I shrink my browser in your code snippet. Can you edit your question so I can help you?

Comment: I have some other things in a media query to convert to a mobile friendly platform with @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) so the text in this carousel disappears right under that and I can't figure out why

Comment: Unless you provide all the applicable code it's impossible to give you a helpful response. Consider dropping it in a Codepen.